# Sorting post by custom fileds date

Tags: custom-field

This code show only less date or equal today date.

How I can to show expired posts ?

**It's a code**

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_archive_eventos' );

function custom_post_type_archive_eventos( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()  ) {

        $today =  date('Y-m-d');

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page','6' );


        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'Data_START',
            'value'     => $today,
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'DATE',
        ),
           array(
            'key'       => 'Data_END',
            'value'     => $today,
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'DATE',
        ),

      ));
    }
}
```

In finally I need to have to this order:

1) Not expired posts

2) Rest... (expired posts)

### UPDATE

Exists 3 type of posts with and without custom fileds.

1) Post without custom fields

2) Post with only custom field :

`Data_START` : **2018-02-20**

3) Post with two custom fields :

`Data_START` **2018-02-20**

`Data_END` **2018-02-22**

**And so**

---> no data

---> only starty data : **2018-02-20**

--- start and end data : **2018-02-20** **2018-02-22**

I need to show for first all valid posts and rest (all expired and without data posts)

Comment: Why don't you sort only by `Data_END`? This would satisfy both your conditions.

Comment: Because some post have Data_END and other have only Data_START (I am not define Data_END if Event have only 1 day)

Comment: You should provide example data and expected result of that data. Otherwise its unclear what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Topic has updated

Comment: I don't think you can use your custom field's date the same way you use `date_query`. I assume `meta_query` would simply compare the strings, rather than being smart and comparing the date.

Comment: Where are you see the data_query ? it's all `meta_query` or  Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code

```
function university_adjust_queries( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'program' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'event' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $today = date( 'Ymd' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value'   => $today,
                'type'    => 'numeric',
            )
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'university_adjust_queries' );
```

Comment: Not sure where did you get two CPTs! And seems you didn't answer his question. Could you please explain how this code solves his problem?